# Testing Javascript (Server: Node.js, Client: React - Redux - Saga)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, redux-saga

*A quick disclaimer: I am not having issues, I am simply asking for guidance. I don't feel like the other topics provide a guiding point towards a particular style of testing or library rather than just helping other with their actual choice of library and style.*

Hey guys! I was thinking, is there anyone in here that could provide me with some guidance for unit testing? What kind of testing do I want (I am a newbie)? e2e, tdd, bdd etc.? Any particular recommendations for libraries and good practices? I am currently working on a React Redux-Saga project and a node backend that we'd like to start testing as well. Is there library that we can use for both or do we need two different since it is essentially two different projects (Client, Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of test runners out there, I would recommend using Jest its easy to setup full featured and has good documentation and maintained by Facebook. Enzyme is the de facto standard for parsing react components and traversing the DOM, although is just a wrapper around Reacts native test utils.

- https://facebook.github.io/jest/
- https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme

You don't need different testing libraries for client and server code at a unit level. Although for end to end testing / integration testing you do need a different runner generally one that includes selenium, although there are some great alternatives out there at the moment.

Here is a doc I put together outlining some [React testing fundamentals](https://github.com/nikglavin/react-testing-fundamentals)

[cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/) looks like an interesting new platform for writing end to end test without the need for selenium making it faster and more stable.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your quick reply! I am familiar with React and have been working with it for some time now, same goes for redux and sagas. Unit-testing is what is new to me, which I think it shouldn't be. I've been seeing JEST all over the internet but like other aspects of Javascript and its libraries, there is a fatigue. I don't know what to choose and why. I will take a look at your doc and absorb as much information as possible. Is it possible for you to provide information as what I would want to start off with? Just to "quality check" my code?

Comment: Would JEST be fine, also which category does it fall under?

Comment: Yes jest would be fine there isn't a lot of difference between the runners but Jest is full featured and maintained by facebook. You can do unit / module and behavioural testing with Jest .

Answer (score 0):

`jest` is a very good option if you're working with both `nodejs` and `react`.

For a good practice, I would recommend trying to apply [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) so that your source code will have good separation of concerns and testability.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your response! Okay, will definitely look at JEST since it seems like it lives up to its hype. Will also read up on the "Clean Architecture". :D